# breaking a graph into two by removing 4 edges

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a simple planar 4-valent graph.  I want to find out
how to break it into two pieces by removing 4 edges, if such a way exists.
Removing the four edges belonging to a single vertex doesn't count.

```
 I know how to do this in O(v^4) operations, where v is the number
```

of vertices, specifically by trying each possible removal of 4 edges.
Is there a method faster than O(v^4) for searching for a way to do this?
I have a lot of graphs to work with.  Thanks.